# freetds: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: homebrew, freetds

I'm installing freetds using `brew install freetds` on my Mac. But I get an error like this:

```
/bin/sh ../../../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link clang -D_THREAD_SAFE  -g -O2 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include -Wdeclaration-after-statement  -L/usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.2/lib -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/lib -o fisql fisql.o terminal.o edit.o handlers.o interrupt.o ../../dblib/libsybdb.la ../../replacements/libreplacements.la -lssl -lcrypto -liconv -lncurses  -lreadline 
libtool: link: clang -D_THREAD_SAFE -g -O2 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include -Wdeclaration-after-statement -o .libs/fisql fisql.o terminal.o edit.o handlers.o interrupt.o  -L/usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.2/lib -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/lib ../../dblib/.libs/libsybdb.dylib ../../replacements/.libs/libreplacements.a -lssl -lcrypto -liconv -lncurses -lreadline
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_rl_on_new_line", referenced from:
      _main in fisql.o
  "_rl_reset_line_state", referenced from:
      _main in fisql.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [fisql] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
==> Configuration
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.5
HEAD: 4042f42ecb17c6372f0b23690a0f291697d06da1
CPU: 8-core 64-bit sandybridge
OS X: 10.8.5-x86_64
Xcode: 5.0.2
CLT: 5.0.1.0.1.1377666378
X11: N/A
==> ENV
HOMEBREW_CC: clang
HOMEBREW_CXX: clang++
MAKEFLAGS: -j8
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /usr/local
CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH: /usr/include/libxml2:/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers
CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Libraries
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR: /usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Library/ENV/pkgconfig/10.8
HOMEBREW_VERBOSE: 1
ACLOCAL_PATH: /usr/local/share/aclocal
PATH: /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3:/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/unixodbc/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

So what's wrong with my Mac? I installed freetds before without any errors, but this time I don't know why it happens..

Comment: I solved by myself.

Just `brew uninstall readline` && `brew install readline`

Something wrong with this lib.