# Unable to install tiny_tds on mac

Tags: ruby, tiny-tds

I am trying to set up a new mac and have been unable to get tiny_tds to compile. I am running OSX Mojave (10.14.6) and have ruby 2.4.5 installed via asdf. When I try to bundle, installing tiny_tds fails and the logs show:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_dbanydatecrack", referenced from:
      _t in conftest-f13825.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I have searched for this and largely the only solutions I have found suggested are to `brew install freetds` which I've already done, and to try and run it with:

```
sudo ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install tiny_tds
```

Which does not work either.

I'm open to any suggestions, I had tiny_tds installed fine on my last mac and I'm not sure what's different here. From my memory, all I've ever had to do was brew install freetds and then bundle.

Comment: For what it's worth I just did a recent reinstall of 10.14.6, and I had no issues doing a `brew install freetds`. So your memory is correct.

Comment: It's a long shot, but per a comment [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22140907/freetds-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64), maybe try reinstalling `readline` via homebrew, and then rebuilding your Ruby from scratch to get it to build with the newly reinstalled `readline`? EDIT: I don't know how `asdf` works but this will only apply if you're building Ruby locally. Maybe try with a Ruby from `rbenv` instead?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So in the end, it turned out that the machine I received was not wiped clean from a previous user and all of my problems are due to there being another gcc as well as ancient tds libraries in /usr/local. Blowing away all that stuff has resolved my issues.

Comment: I recommend explaining in greater detail what "blowing away all that stuff" means to assist anyone else that may experience a similar issue in the future.

Comment: Huh?  Could you specify what kind of version of `tiny_tds` did you use with what ruby?  I don't think the latest `tiny_tds` will work your specified ruby version.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you have old ruby.  In your case you have ruby `2.4.5`.

From quick check of the [source code](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds/blob/d8cb94e1033d124dfdd5a08780a530fd8c995101/ext/tiny_tds/result.c) I think you need to have ruby `2.6.0` or newer for the latest `tiny_tds` gem.