# Error when trying to build FreeTDS: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: macos, makefile

When trying to build [freeTDS](http://www.freetds.org) for MacCatalyst, I get the following error in my terminal:

```
sqlwchar.c:104:2: error: SIZEOF_SQLWCHAR not supported !!
#error SIZEOF_SQLWCHAR not supported !!
```

I am not so familiar with auto tools, but I tried to have a look at my log file and it looks like some linking is failing, but I am not experienced enough to find the cause or a fix. The log says:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_shl_load", referenced from:
      _main in conftest-8b1257.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

and many additional errors following like:

```
ld: library not found for -ldld
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
configure:14459: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "FreeTDS"
```

I tried to fix using by using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22140907/freetds-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64) fix without any success. What is the issue? Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: It's unclear what step is failing here, but that you get to the point of the reported error in `sqlwchar.c` suggests that `configure` completed successfully.  In that case, its log probably is not indicative of the nature of the problem.  The code around that `#error` directive in `sqlwchar.c` will clarify the specific conditions that were met in order for that directive to have been processed.

Comment: More information is needed, but the answer may simply be that freeTDS does not support MacOS.

Comment: Hey @JohnBollinger thanks for your comment. I know that FreeTDS can be built for MacOS because it has been built for iPhones, Macs and MacCatalyst already. The code around the error section is: `#if SIZEOF_SQLWCHAR == 2 [...] #elif SIZEOF_SQLWCHAR == 4 [...] #else
#error SIZEOF_SQLWCHAR not supported !!
#endif`
Does this help identifying the problem?

Comment: That someone has managed to build the package for MacOS / iOS does not mean that it *supports* those systems, though the docs seem to [say](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/osissues.html#osx) that it works (or some version did) at least on MacOS (or some version of it).  Apple has a bad history of breaking things, so that doesn't mean that the freeTDS version you're trying to build will work with the build tools your are trying to use.

Comment: Looking more deeply at the error, however, it appears that `configure` is probably failing to determine a needed parameter, most likely on account of not finding an external header `sql.h`.  This may indicate that you do not have a driver manager installed, as discussed in the "ODBC Preparation" section of http://www.freetds.org/userguide/config.html.

Comment: Okay I see. I assumed that it works because there are still apps out there that use FreeTDS to connect iOS apps with Microsoft servers. Okay, that helps a lot! I have seen an error before that said that unixODBC driver was built for MacOS, but not MacCatalyst, but I didn’t know that it could be the source of this error. I will check if this error is in my config.log

Comment: Does `Because FreeTDS won't detect your (missing) DM, it won't automatically build the ODBC driver, so you'll have to tell configure what to do and where to look. Cf. --with-odbc-nodm.` mean that if I build FreeTDS without the driver, it will create the `sysbdb.a` file but FreeTDS won't work? Because I feel like this happened to me. Also, might there be downsides if I just copy and paste `sql.h, sqlext.h and sqltypes.h` instead of installing a full driver?

Comment: Strangely, if I copy these files and add them manually, then configuring with `--with-odbc-nodm="/usr/local/include"` my terminal complains that `configure: error: sql.h not found` although it is in this directory?